# I got 0x9E parameter error while Credit value file on DESFire card

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I now work with value files on DESFire cards. I created a value file in my DESFire card with the following command:

```
byte[] cmdCreateValueFile = new byte[]{
        //cmd
        (byte)0xCC,
        //file no
        (byte)0x01, 
        //com.sett.
        (byte)0x00 ,
        //access rights
        (byte)0x44 , (byte)0x44,
        //lower limit
        (byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,
        //upper limit
        (byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x0F ,(byte)0x42 ,(byte)0x40 ,
        //initial value
        (byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,
        //limited credit enabled
        (byte)0x00
};
```

I then credit the value of file with this command:

```
//select my app first
...
doAuthenticate(); //authenticate with key #4 of my application

//credit in value file
tagResponse_cmdcredit = isodep.transceive(Utils.wrapMessage(
        (byte)0x0C, new byte[]{(byte) 0x01 , 
        //data
        (byte)0x00,(byte)0x00, (byte)0x03 , (byte)0xE8}));
Log.d("credittttttttttt", "111 "+Utils.bytesToHex(tagResponse_cmdcredit));

//do commit transaction
tagResponse_cmdCommitTransaction = isodep.transceive(Utils.wrapMessage(
        (byte)0xC7, null));
Log.d("committtttttttt", "111 "+Utils.bytesToHex(tagResponse_cmdCommitTransaction));
```

And my wrapMessage helper method looks like this:

```
public static byte[] wrapMessage (byte command, byte[] parameters) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    stream.write((byte) 0x90);
    stream.write(command);
    stream.write((byte) 0x00);
    stream.write((byte) 0x00);
    if (parameters != null) {
        stream.write((byte) parameters.length);
        stream.write(parameters);
    }
    stream.write((byte) 0x00);

    byte[] b = stream.toByteArray();
    return b;
}
```

But I recieve `91 9E` error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
I found My mistake! I didnt heed MSB and LSB value initializing in the create value file command. It must be like this if lower limit be *0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00*(zero) and upper value be *0x0F 0x42 0x40*(1000 000):

```
tagResponse_cmdcreateValueFile = isodep.transceive(Utils.wrapMessage((byte)0xCC, new byte[]{(byte)0x01, 
                        //com.sett.
                        (byte)0x00 ,
                        //access rights
                        (byte)0x44 , (byte)0x44,
                        //lower limit
                        (byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,
                        //upper limit
                        (byte)0x40 ,(byte)0x42 ,(byte)0x0F ,(byte)0x00 ,
                        //initial value
                        (byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,
                        //limited credit enabled
                        (byte)0x00}));
```

---

I found my mistake! According to the DESFire documentation the value is always represented as **LSB first**.

When I want credit an amount of 1000 for example, I need to pass

```
(byte)0xE8, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00
```

to the command instead of `0x00 0x00 0x03 0xE8` (where `03E8` is 1000 in decimal). When passing the value with MSB first, this would result in the decimal value -402456576 (signed 4-byte integer), which would be above the upper limit.

Comment: @Michael my answer is correct? I send '(byte)0xE8, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00' but when I get value It is not same amount which I expect!

Comment: Your answer looks fine. What value do you get and what did you expect? Also, did you do a cleanup (i.e. delete and recreate the file) after crediting the wrong value?

Comment: Yes I did recreation the file. I am so amazed! I send this: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0A (10 $) credit did successfully and i get value properly. for example in step 1: sending 0x00 0x00  0x00 0x0A and getValue command returns 0A, step 2: sending 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0A and getValue command returns 0x14. in step 3: I send 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xE8 and this time getValue command returns 0x9E error.

Comment: I want credit 1000 $ (0x00 0x00 0x03 0xE8) But recieve 0x9E error.